# How to catch DateParseError in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I am running a script that uses `pd.to_datetime()` on inputs that are sometime not able to be parsed.

For example if I try to run `pd.to_datetime('yesterday')` it results to an error

`DateParseError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: yesterday, at position 0`

I 'd like to catch this exception and process it further in my code.

I have tried:

```
try:
    pd.to_datetime('yesterday')
except pd.errors.ParserError:
    print('exception caught')
```

but the exception is not caught. Does anyone know where `DateParseError` is defined and how I can catch it? Searching in [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/search.html?q=DateParseError) doesn't yield any results

Comment: Side note, it's a shame that `'yesterday'` is not understood as a valid timestamp (since `'today'` is valid).

Comment: totally agree with you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import it from `pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing`:

```
from pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing import DateParseError

try:
    pd.to_datetime('yesterday')
except DateParseError:
    print('exception caught')
```